# Client and Server is not linking properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

My node server is not working properly, as I am following a video tutorial for a real-time chat app, In the video tutorial shows that the node server is working fine but with the same code, it is not working properly and when I add a name in the **Prompt** section, it is not showing in the server. My whole code is as follows:

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>iChat - Realtime Node Socket.io Chat App</title>
    <script defer src='http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
    <script defer src="js/client.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <img class="logo"src="icon.png" alt="">
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="message right">Ravi:Hi</div>
        <div class="message left">Sonam:Hi</div>
    </div>

    <div class="send">
        <form action="#" id="send-container">
            <input type="text" name="messageInp" id="messageInp">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Send</button>

        </form>
    </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
const { Socket } = require("socket.io");

const io = require("socket.io")(8000);

const users = {};

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("new-user-joined", (name) => {
    console.log("New user", name);
    users[socket.id] = name;
    socket.broadcast.emit("user-joined", name);
  });

  socket.on("send", (message) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("receive", {
      message: message,
      name: user[socket.id],
    });
  });
});
```

**client.js**

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:8000");

const form = document.getElementById("send-container");
const messageInput = document.getElementById("messageInp");
const messageContainer = document.querySelector(".container");

const append = (message, position) => {
  const messageElement = document.createElement("div");
  messageElement.innerText = message;
  messageElement.classList.add("message");
  messageElement.classList.add(position);
  messageContainer.append(messageElement);
};

const name = prompt("Enter name your to join");
socket.emit("new-user-joined", name);

socket.on("user-joined", (name) => {
  append(`${name} joined the chat`, "right");
});
```

Please help me as I am just started to learn Node.Js.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: you need to move the logic to join a room on click of the button, as it currently is, its just going to emit off a join to a room with an empty value on page load not when you click submit

Comment: Any error messages? Or just "not working"

Comment: `GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O8HxyS8 net::ERR_FAILED 200`  `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O8Hy4lV' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` These two errors are looping again and again in the browser's console

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS, it may ever help you.

Answer (score 0):

**For Cross Origin**

```
const server = app.listen(config.port, () => {
  logger.info(`Web channel manager listening to port ${config.port}`, { className: "index.js", methodName: "app.listen" });
});
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*"
  }
});
```